# how to reset seletion focus text node when use innerHTML changed focus node

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I try make markdown rich text editor with use ContentEditable element and want make markdown source code have some style,so write this parser:

```
<body>
    <div class="editor-content" ContentEditable="true" onKeyUp="inputChanges"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let inputChanges = (event) => {

        //old selection info
        let selection = window.getSelection();
        let oldRange = selection.anchorOffset;
        let oldContainer = selection.anchorNode;

        let markdown = event.target.innerTex;

        let parserArray = [...];
        for (const i of parserArray) {
            markdown = markdown.replace(i.EXP, i.todo);
        }

        event.target.innerHTML = markdown;

        // I tried below to make cursor back

        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(oldContainer);
        range.setStart(oldContainer, oldRange);
        range.collapse(true);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
</script>
```

when typing the cursor will go first of editor.
I try to fix but it report a error:
**The given range isn't in document.**

check the selection before innerHTML executed and after:
[first after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIeoO.png)

I guess it's selection focus node's problem.If it's how to trun the focus to text node?

(text node is ContentEditable div's text`<div class="editor-content" ContentEditable="true" onKeyUp="inputChanges">[here is the text node]</div>`)

---

Comment: well, I think the best answer is use CodeMirror. http://codemirror.net/.